# Retour plugin pages blank

Tags: plugin-retour

After directing our domain to the server, the Retour plugin has shown only blank pages, with "No relevant data" messages displayed instead of information.

However, we are able to create shortlinks via the relevant field, as well as add redirects via the plugin, although cannot see or amend any redirects which exist.

I turned Cloudflare off temporarily but that has not changed anything. The Javascript console gives me a "Mixed content" message, despite https being forced, and baseCpUrl defined in general.php is with https://.

I've been going around in circles on threads here and one on the plugin's github which showed a similar but not identical issue. I am not having issues with any other plugins, just this one so any suggestions to try would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have Cloudflare's Rocket Loader on or such, try disabling it.

Also in general, you don't want Cloudflare active for the Craft CP at all.

Also please check what your site URL is set to?

Answer (score 0):

I checked and Rocket Loader was not on - though have disabled Cloudflare completely for the admin URL - bar /cpanel (or equivalent) are there any other URLs that the CP uses that I should also add exceptions for? This so far hasn't changed anything.

I can however download the .csv now via the button, which I couldn't previously (so, some functionality I can make use of!). I just can't see any of the data on the page/s.

Site URL is the equivalent of https://site.com in the .env and that's called as the base URL in settings too.